# Entity Framework Power Tools does not appear in VS 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have installed EntityFramework 6.01 and have added a reference to my project.  I closed Visual Studio 2012 and I then installed EF Power Tools Beta 4.

I re-opened Visual Studio 2012 and right-clicked my project containing dbContext.  No entry appears in the context menu for Entity Framework. No error messages occurred during installation.

Are there additional pre-requisites to using EF Power Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have discovered the solution.  My company uses VB.net as the standard development language.  As a test, I started a C# project.  Entity Framework Power Tools are fully present in the C# project.  It appears that Entity Framework Power Tools are not yet available in VB.net projects.

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem but I'm in VS 2013 and I'm not in a VB.net project like you are.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on the project. I just looked at the beta 4 description and it does not reference EF 6. But the reverse engineer classes from database should show up with a right click on the project, indicating that at least the power tools installed correctly. These are the only comparability issues I could find:

> Generate Views won’t work with prerelease versions of EF6. 
>   It will, however, work with the RTM version when it’s released.
>   View Entity Data Model won’t work with EF6 on Visual Studio 2010.
>
> Beta 4 updates the Power Tools to work with Entity Framework 6 and Visual Studio 2013. The following issues have also been fixed in this release.
>   Power Tools don't work when project is under a solution folder
>   Power Tools stop working when EF.dll is loaded into VS

Specific info found on the ado.net blog on msdn

Comment: No joy - I checked Tools | Extensions and Updates - this shows Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4 with options to disable or uninstall - so I assume this has been installed. No reverse engineering or Entity Framework items appear on any project menu.  I have tried this on two separated development boxes with the same result.

Comment: Which service pack for visual studio and which version pro ultimate other?

Comment: Hi Mike - I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 with Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2.

Comment: Apply update 3 and reinstall ef powertools ( that matches the environment I am using currently)